# The name 'Vector3' does not exists in the current context. [Unity][C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make a simple game but mono develop does not recognize a `Vector3` object. I am using Unity 5.

[image]

Comment: Try deleting Library in the root folder

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson Hey man I I tried to search for the folder but I could not find it.

Comment: It's in root project folder, but if reinstalling didn't work then this probably won't.

Answer (score -1):

Well known solution to this is problem to **uninstall** Unity and Mono then install it again. The problem should go away. If the problem still persist, you should try **visual Studio Community** which comes with Unity.

Comment: Yup I know but when I try to use vs it get stuck loading... :(

Comment: Ok. How about you just forget visual studio and try uninstall, install again.

Comment: Nope still did not work man, when I reinstalled unity it gave me this error: http://prntscr.com/akeloh and when monostudio opens it gives me this error: http://prntscr.com/akemdy

Comment: Completely uninstall Unity, MonoDevelop and Visual Studio. Restart system. Install Visual Studio Community. Install Unity without MonoDevelop.

Comment: J.Doe do what Thomas said. Also, what Operating System version are you running this on?